# MySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE error

Tags: mysql, file-upload, csv

I am trying to upload 50K+ rows of data for the following table with the below, but getting a query ok, 0 rows affected message:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ConsumerAlpha.HS6Data (
  hs6DataID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  hs6Category INT NOT NULL,
  countryID INT NOT NULL,
  year INT NOT NULL,
  dataCode VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  hsValue DEC(20,2) NULL,
  hsWeight DEC(20,2) NULL,
  hsQuantity DEC(20,2) NULL,
  hsUnitID INT NOT NULL,
  dateCreated DATE NOT NULL ,
  lastModified DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  dateDeleted DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL ,  
  PRIMARY KEY (hs6DataID) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX hs6DataID_UNIQUE (hs6DataID),
  CONSTRAINT hs6DataCategories
    FOREIGN KEY (hs6Category)
    REFERENCES ConsumerAlpha.HS6CategoriesR02 (hs6Category)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT hs6DataUnits
    FOREIGN KEY (hsUnitID)
    REFERENCES ConsumerAlpha.HSUnits (hsUnitID)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT hs6DataCountries
    FOREIGN KEY (countryID)
    REFERENCES ConsumerAlpha.Countries (countryID)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT hs6DataCode
    FOREIGN KEY (dataCode)
    REFERENCES ConsumerAlpha.DataSources (dataCode )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Here's my `LOAD DATA LOCAL` command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL 
INFILE '/Users/Esperto007/Dropbox/Data/DataBase/Tables/ComTrade/hsImports_1988.csv' 
INTO TABLE ConsumerAlpha.HS6Data
fields terminated by ','
optionally enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\r'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(hs6Category, countryID, year, dataCode, hsValue, hsWeight, hsQuantity, hsUnitID, dateCreated)
SET dateCreated = NOW();
```

The .csv data conform to data types in the definition, and come without an index column in the exact order as indicated after `IGNORE 1 LINES`. This already worked yesterday before I made some changes to the python script that generates the table mainly to 'clean up the code'.. Any help appreciated.

Comment: and the error is...? without that, we can only assume the error code is `PEBKAC`.

Comment: @MarcB He said he's not getting an error, just 0 rows inserted.

Comment: I suggest you find a backup of the input file from yesterday, and compare it to today's, to see what you broke when you made those python changes.

Comment: Are you *sure* that the line termination is `\r` alone?  That's pretty uncommon (Apple used to use it before they moved to OS-X)... I suspect your newline is some other character sequence; indeed, if it were `\n` alone (common on *nix-based systems), `\r` may never appear and thus `IGNORE 1 LINES` may cause the entire file to be ignored.

Comment: Agree with @eggyal probably your line terminator should be `\n` or `\r\n`

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. Unfortunately, it's not the line terminator; it works if I exclude the hs6Category variable from the `LOAD DATA LOCAL` statement. I can't figure out what's wrong with the variable, with data types matching and all.